# Aligning a text file in vba

Tags: vba, excel

My application is in vba and I want to log information in text file which required four columns. The tool should open the log file and log the issue and close the file immediately so that other processes running in parallel could also post the issues to it without loss of data. Keep appending to the log file. Also if string is too long for last column then it should be broken into parts and all part should come under last column one by one in proper alignment.

```
Sub ExportToTXT()

Dim fName As String
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim Widths(1 To 4) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim lngR As Long

lngR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

fName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Export Fixed width columns.txt"

On Error GoTo EndMacro:
FNum = FreeFile

'These are the desired column widths in the text file

Widths(1) = 30
Widths(2) = 40
Widths(3) = 50
Widths(4) = 80

Open fName For Append Access Write As #FNum
WholeLine = ""
WholeLine = WholeLine & Left("Value for first column" & String(Widths(1), " "), Widths(1))
WholeLine = WholeLine & Left("Value for second column" & String(Widths(2), " "), Widths(2))
WholeLine = WholeLine & Left("Value for third column" & String(Widths(3), " "), Widths(3))
WholeLine = WholeLine & Left("Value for fourth column" & String(Widths(4), " "), Widths(4))
Print #FNum, WholeLine
```

EndMacro:
    On Error GoTo 0
     Close #FNum

```
End Sub
```

Comment: *Please* post your code.

Comment: I am looking for code Nanashi..

Comment: Sadly, that is not how SO works. We help with the code for practical purposes and answer programming-related theoretical questions. For the latter, no code is required. However, for the former, if you're looking for help with your program, it will be best if you show some understanding of your code by *writing* some and asking for help here when it stumps you. :)

Comment: Thankx for your suggestion guys, to make it more clear I have written code and edited in my post. This code is working fine but what I want is if the value of any column exceeds its maximum width then rest of the value should come exactly below that column without disturbing any columns alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone I got the solution, below is the code I am using
thanx for your valueable time. :)

```
Sub WriteTo_CommonLogFile(First_30Char As String, Second_40Char As String, Third_40Char As String, Fourth_50Char As String)

Dim StrVal As String
Dim StartFrom As Long, EndUpTo As Long
Dim Limit As Double
Dim j As Long
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(Form_TopLevel.Txt_Bx_Error_LogFile.Value, 8, True)
        If Len(Fourth_50Char) > 50 Then
            Limit = Module5.Ceiling(Len(Fourth_50Char) / 50, 1)
            StartFrom = 1
            EndUpTo = 50
            For j = 0 To Limit - 1
                StrVal = VBA.MID$(Fourth_50Char, StartFrom, EndUpTo)

                If j = 0 Then
                    .WriteLine " "
                    .WriteLine VBA.Format(First_30Char, "!" & VBA.String(30, "@")) & VBA.Format(Second_40Char, "!" & VBA.String(40, "@")) _
                    & VBA.Format(Third_40Char, "!" & VBA.String(40, "@")) & VBA.Format(StrVal, "!" & VBA.String(50, "@"))
                Else
                    .WriteLine VBA.Space(110) & StrVal
                End If
                StartFrom = StartFrom + 50
            Next j
        Else
            .WriteLine " "
            .WriteLine VBA.Format(First_30Char, "!" & VBA.String(30, "@")) & VBA.Format(Second_40Char, "!" & VBA.String(40, "@")) _
                       & VBA.Format(Third_40Char, "!" & VBA.String(40, "@")) & VBA.Format(Fourth_50Char, "!" & VBA.String(50, "@"))
        End If
    .Close
End With
End Sub


Function Ceiling(ByVal x As Double, Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
' X is the value you want to round
' is the multiple to which you want to round
Ceiling = (Int(x / Factor) - (x / Factor - Int(x / Factor) > 0)) * Factor
End Function
```

thanx a lot everyone...:)